# Android - Can't refresh user location on activity launch

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-location, locationmanager, android-maps

I'm stuck trying to refresh the user's location.

In my app, I start the map marking user's current location, but `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` is returning a different location
because it uses a cache location.

How can I compare the last known location with the current location so I can mark the correct position on the map in the callback `OnMapReady`?

Every example I found in StackOverflow is using `LocationListener.onLocationChanged()` method, but I need to refresh the location (if needed) on activity launch.

**Code:**

```
private static final String TAG_MAP_LOAD_FAILED = "FAIL LOADING MAP STYLE";
private static final String TAG_MAP_PARSING_FAILED = "FAIL PARSING MAP STYLE";

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LatLng mMyCoordinates;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    try{
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.style_mapjson));

        if(!success){
            Log.e(TAG_MAP_PARSING_FAILED, "Failed parsing JSON Style");
        }

    }catch (Resources.NotFoundException ex){
        Log.e(TAG_MAP_LOAD_FAILED, "Can't find style. Error:", ex);
    }


    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(mMyCoordinates);
    markerOptions.title("Marker in my location");
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMyCoordinates, 15);
    mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

OBS: I cleaned up the code because it was getting full of unsuccessful attempts. Just showing how it is structured.

**Should I use `FusedLocation` instead?**

Comment: Yes. `LocationManager` uses a different implementation and I don't think you can use it with a `GoogleMap` to get connection callbacks. Where'd you got that idea from? You need an API client for that. Why you look for answers first in SO rather than in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) is a matter of another forum. Try giving it a read until the very end and you will have this solved. And yes, use `FusedLocation` unless you want to use deprecated code

Answer (score 1):

The last known location has a timestamp associated with it, which can be quite some time in the past. Just do an age comparison with the last known location's timestamp with the max age you'd allow, and request an update when needed. Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
private static long MAX_TIME = 60 * 60 * 1000; //Update if location is older than one hour

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(YOUR_PROVIDER_HERE); //GPS or Network

    boolean shouldUpdateLocation = false;
    if (location != null) {
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - location.getTime();
        if (elapsedTime >= MAX_TIME) {
            shouldUpdateLocation = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        shouldUpdateLocation = true;
    }

    if (shouldUpdateLocation) {
        //TODO: Request location update here.
    }
}
```

You don't want to be requesting location updates every time the activity is brought up, so set up a reasonable MAX_TIME for this.

Comment: Thanks, Pablo. One more question: should i use `requestSingleUpdate()` to get the refreshed location?

Comment: You can, although I would use `requestLocationUpdates()` and stop it once I get a location with a decent accuracy.

Comment: I will test it and update the question if this is the solution! Thanks!